# Using a Angular controller to show JSON data from API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Om using Angular to show data from a JSON object from an API. This is my controller:

```
angular.module('todoApp', []).controller('ListController', function($http) {
    var todoList = this;

    todoList.todos = [{"id":1,"uname":"BluePrint","pname":"Birdie","content":"DHSvahdgsvadjavsdj","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"},{"id":2,"uname":"BluePrint","pname":"Fiskpinne","content":"gggggggggggggggggggg","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"},{"id":3,"uname":"BluePrint","pname":"KulGrej","content":"hdbjsdhfgjsdhfg","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"},{"id":4,"uname":"Howken","pname":"KulGrej","content":"xczzzzz","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"},{"id":5,"uname":"Howken","pname":"Birdie","content":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"},{"id":6,"uname":"Howken","pname":"Fiskpinne","content":"\u00e5\u00e4\u00f6\u00e5\u00e4\u00f6\u00e5","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"},{"id":7,"uname":"Howken","pname":"KulGrej","content":"sssssggggg","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"}];
    console.log([{"id":1,"uname":"BluePrint","pname":"Birdie","content":"DHSvahdgsvadjavsdj","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"},{"id":2,"uname":"BluePrint","pname":"Fiskpinne","content":"gggggggggggggggggggg","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"},{"id":3,"uname":"BluePrint","pname":"KulGrej","content":"hdbjsdhfgjsdhfg","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"},{"id":4,"uname":"Howken","pname":"KulGrej","content":"xczzzzz","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"},{"id":5,"uname":"Howken","pname":"Birdie","content":"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"},{"id":6,"uname":"Howken","pname":"Fiskpinne","content":"\u00e5\u00e4\u00f6\u00e5\u00e4\u00f6\u00e5","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"},{"id":7,"uname":"Howken","pname":"KulGrej","content":"sssssggggg","completed":0,"removed":0,"added":"2015-12-30 16:30:52","deadline":"2015-12-30 16:30:52"}]);

    todoList.todos2 = 
        $http({method : 'GET',url : 'http://localhost:8000/notes'})
            .success(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                return [data];
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                alert("Error");
            });
});
```

And this is my `html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/ListController.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Todo</h2>
    <div ng-controller="ListController as todoList">
      <ul class="unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todoList.todos2">
          {{ todo.content }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm debugging by using the raw data from my test API as `todoList.todos` and the function that should generate the "real" data as `todoList.todos2`.

Using my raw data gives the correct answer (a list of the "content" elements in each JSON object), but using todo2 only gives me two empty list elements in the list.

The URL in the controller gives me the correct JSON data, I have checked that.

You can see printscreens on the results when working and not working here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWKN9.jpg

Where did I do it wrong?

Comment: why you are returning [data] instead of data?

Comment: Did you try `$http({method : 'GET',url : 'http://localhost:8000/notes'})
            .success(function(data, status) {
                console.log(data);
                this.todoList.todos2 = data;
            })
            .error(function(data, status) {
                alert("Error");
            });`

Comment: @IgnacioChiazzo I was doing some trial and error to see if I could find out what was wrong. I had `data` only at first and I just forgot to remove the brackets before posting here...

Comment: If your api is returning JSON, I would suggest you use $resource instead of $http.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the $http service returns a promise, it dose not return JSON data.

here is the using of $http service.

```
angular.module('todoApp', []).controller('ListController', function($http) {
    var todoList = this;

    $http({method : 'GET',url : 'http://localhost:8000/notes'})
       .then(function(response) {
           console.log(response.data);
           todoList.todos2 = response.data;
       }, function() {
           alert("Error");
       });
});
```

Comment: The `.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated -- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Comment: The `.then` method returns a response object not `(data, status)`. Please read the Docs.

Comment: Should be `.then (function  (response) { todolist.todos2 = response.data; });`

Answer (score 0):

The `.success` and `.error` functions are deprecated, and `$http` returns a promise that is *resolved* with the response object, hence:

```
$http.get(...).then(function(res) {
    todoList.todos2 = res.data;
}).catch(e) {
    alert(e);
});
```

However I'd urge you to investigate `$resource` instead of using `$http` directly:

```
app.factory('TodoResource', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('/notes', {}, {
            query: { isArray: true }
        });
    }
]);
```

and then inject that `TodoResource` into your controller:

```
app.controller('ListController', [$scope, 'TodoResource',
    function($scope, TodoResource) {
        $scope.todos2 = TodoResource.query();
    }
]);
```

You can then add RESTful methods to your `TodoResource` object that automatically handle inserts, updates and deletes.